# Epimorphism of algebras restricted to ring of invariants

Tags: commutative-algebra, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is an affine algebraic group that acts rationally on $K$-algebras $R$ and $R'$, ie every element is contained in a rational representation: a finite-dimensional $G$-stable vector subspace $V$ such that the map $G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ is a homomorphism of algebraic groups. Further suppose that every rational representation of $G$ is completely reducible.

Exercise 1 in Section 14 of Humphreys' *Linear Algebraic Groups* asks to show that if $\varphi : R \to R'$ is a $G$-equivariant *epimorphism* then the restriction $R^G \to (R')^G$ is *onto*. This is not correct as stated, taking $G = \{e\}$, not every epimorphism of $K$-algebras is onto, eg $K[X] \hookrightarrow K(X)$.

There are two obvious ways of modifying this statement. I believe the intended exercise is to show that if $\varphi$ is onto then so is its restriction $R^G \to (R')^G$. This is not difficult and is indeed useful in solving the next exercise as indicated.

Alternatively, one could consider the question: **if $\varphi$ is an epimorphism, must the restriction $R^G \to (R')^G$ be an epimorphism?** This seems less obvious, even for localizations, and a general epimorphism is not always a composition of quotients and localizations (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like). Is there any hope of solving this variant of the exercise?

If $G$ is a *finite* group and $R \to R' = S^{-1}R$ is a localization (with $GS \subset S$, which is wlog by equivariance) then it is not so hard to see that $(R')^G = (S^G)^{-1}(R^G)$ using the fact that $\prod_{g \in G} (g \cdot a) \in R^G$ for $a \in R$.